# update product inventory and and price by attribute

Tags: php, database, inventory, crontab

I need to write a cron job to update my products inventory and price hourly.

The variables are these.

I have 6000 products with their own IDs which my accounting system uses (not magento).

These 6000 turn into 31,000 products. The reason for this is they are car parts, so a Mazda 3 may use the same part as a Honda civic, users on my site will be searching by make, model, and year (all attributes). The only way I could figure out how to do this by importing 31,000 different parts (so they have 31,000 magento IDs).

So I have also imported my accounting system ID as an attribute (my_part_id) which all products have.

So I would like my cron to search for all products which have my_part_id and update the qty and price.

Can someone please point me in the right direction to get this done? I am very comfortable using PHP and MYSQL, I just don't fully understand the Magento Database yet and don't want to mess up any table relationships that I don't know about.

Comment: Got any code implemented yet ?

Comment: hello, not yet, I don't know where to start looking. I basically need a way to inner join products to attributes using an attribute value, then inner join that to product inventory

Comment: If you are comfortable with PHP and SQL, take a look at here http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/updating-product-qty-in-magento-in-an-easier-faster-way/, this might give you a head start. Please check in a dev environment first though.

Answer (score 0):

I have to do something similar in one of my Magento2 projects, I have to update product price and quantity but based on product id.
I have used public function `updateAttributes($productIds, $attrData, $storeId)` in file `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Action.php` to update price.
For updating the quantity, I have used the following code in my custom module.

```
$product = $this->productFactory->create()->load($productId);
$product->setStockData(['qty' => $newqty, 'is_in_stock' => $newss]);
$product->save();
```

You can modify the code according to your requirement. 
I hope this will help you.